# Trouble Sending SMS via Email in PHP

Tags: php, html, email, text, sms

I have been trying for some time now to set up a php script that will send a text message using php's mail function. I have an HTML form asking users for their phone number and carrier, once I've got the phone number and carrier, I store them in a database, and proceed by trying to send an email to {10-digit phone number}@{carrier SMS email}.com.

For example, on Verizon I would send an email to 5555555555@vtext.com. BUT, whenever I do so, none of the text messages go through. I have a Verizon phone and have tried on numerous occasions, yet the messages NEVER come through. When I manually go into my email account and compose an email to myphonenumber@vtext.com, they come through right away!

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="subscribe.php">

<input class= "submitForm"type="text" name="name" id="name">

<input placeholder="No dashes or spaces" class= "submitForm"type="text" name="number" id="number">

<select name="carrier">
<option value="vtext.com">Verizon</option>
<option value="txt.att.net">At&t</option>
<option value="tmomail.net">T-Mobile</option>
</select>
<input value="Submit">
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
//Getting Variables
$name = trim($_POST["name"]);
$number = trim($_POST["number"]);
$carrier = trim($_POST["carrier"]);

//Sending Message
$email = $number . "@" . $carrier;
//echo $email = (for example)
    //5555555555@vtext.com
$to      = $email;
$subject = 'You Have Been Subscribed';
$message = 'Testing';
mail( $to, $subject, $message);

?>
```

Comment: What happens if you use your code to email yourself directly, rather than through an SMS? Also - you're putting user-supplied data directly into email headers, so you'll need to make very, very sure that your code is secure.

Comment: I understand your security concern, however I am not sure what you mean by emailing myself directly? What I want is for users to fill out this HTML form and then have a text message sent to them. Thanks for the help but if possible, could you elaborate any more? THANKS AGAIN

Comment: change the email address to yours, just for a test

Comment: Sure. Change your code so that when it's run, the `$to` is your email address. Run your code; do you get the email? If so, there's an issue with the emails being sent to the SMS providers. If not, then there's a local issue with your server.

Comment: Oh, I understand now. When I just tried that, the email went through to myself RIGHT AWAY, although it did get filtered into my spam folder. Could that have something to do with it?

Comment: if you really want to send sms, dont rely on any carriers email to sms gateway, they are notoriously bad, use a proper sms gateway service

Comment: @Dagon can you recommend any that are easy to use and preferably free?

Comment: @KylePapili - I expect so. I'd guess your emails look like spam just enough that they're getting blocked somewhere along the way. There are ways to fix it, but it's a huge subject.

Comment: none are free. it costs money to send sms

Comment: So, @andrewsi in my case would you recommend I try some of the methods of making an email not get filtered into spam or look elsewhere for a new method of sending SMS? Also, do you think the lack of any headers in my email would affect it's likelihood of being blocked? Again, thanks for all the help!

Comment: Understandable, thank you for the tip @Dagon I will definitely look into getting a proper SMS gateway if I cannot resolve this issue another way. Thanks again

Comment: @KylePapili - Getting a good SMS gateway will be easier; getting your emails to look less spammy is probably cheaper, but trickier.

Comment: @andrewsi Okay, thank's again for the help, I will have to do some further research but this definitely helped me out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After testing my mail function by having it send an email to myself, I realized that although the email arrived, it was filtered into my spam folder. It is likely that the same thing is happening when I send an email to #@vtext.com. This leaves me with two options.

1. Use an SMS Gateway

Although they may cost a bit, an SMS gateway would GUARANTEE the safe delivery of my messages to their recipiants.

2. Implement [Spam Folder Avoidance Tactics](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/email/fighting-spam/stop-emails-being-labeled-spam)

Thanks to all that helped out in the comments section!!

Answer (score 0):

Don't think you "have to" use a (PAY) Gateway... The kind of technique you're using has been used for years without the NEED for a costly Gateway at all. I've done the same technique thru C# and it works GREAT... the city of Cincinnati (Court System) even uses this SAME Technology (NO GATEWAY) to give out SMS Text Alerts for COURT REPORTING Dates: see the attached PIC below for an example: (and NO, the Charge was not 4 MURDER)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cctgc.jpg)